# How do you create a state / county list for the United Kingdom ( UK ) with SelectList in C# .NET ?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, drop-down-menu, states

How can I include United Kingdom counties (states) as a SelectList in my C# .net web application?

I need full name and abbreviation for each county/state.

Please submit any updates (updated April 2014) . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This dictionary is accurate as of 2014.  Post below with any updates to the county list with their corresponding abbreviations.  Thanks!

```
public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> UKStateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> 
    {                    
        {"Aberdeen City","ABE"},
        {"Aberdeenshire","ABD"},
        {"Angus","ANS"},
        {"Antrim","ANT"},
        {"Ards","ARD"},
        {"Argyll and Bute","AGB"},
        {"Armagh","ARM"},
        {"Ballymena","BLA"},
        {"Ballymoney","BLY"},
        {"Banbridge","BNB"},
        {"Barking and Dagenham","BDG"},
        {"Barnet","BNE"},
        {"Barnsley","BNS"},
        {"Bath and North East Somerset","BAS"},
        {"Bedfordshire","BDF"},
        {"Belfast","BFS"},
        {"Bexley","BEX"},
        {"Birmingham","BIR"},
        {"Blackburn with Darwen","BBD"},
        {"Blackpool","BPL"},
        {"Blaenau Gwent","BGW"},
        {"Bolton","BOL"},
        {"Bournemouth","BMH"},
        {"Bracknell Forest","BRC"},
        {"Bradford","BRD"},
        {"Brent","BEN"},
        {"Bridgend [Pen-y-bont ar Ogwr GB-POG]","BGE"},
        {"Brighton and Hove","BNH"},
        {"Bristol, City of","BST"},
        {"Bromley","BRY"},
        {"Buckinghamshire","BKM"},
        {"Bury","BUR"},
        {"Caerphilly [Caerffili GB-CAF]","CAY"},
        {"Calderdale","CLD"},
        {"Cambridgeshire","CAM"},
        {"Camden","CMD"},
        {"Cardiff [Caerdydd GB-CRD]","CRF"},
        {"Carmarthenshire [Sir Gaerfyrddin GB-GFY]","CMN"},
        {"Carrickfergus","CKF"},
        {"Castlereagh","CSR"},
        {"Ceredigion [Sir Ceredigion]","CGN"},
        {"Cheshire","CHS"},
        {"Clackmannanshire","CLK"},
        {"Coleraine","CLR"},
        {"Conwy","CWY"},
        {"Cookstown","CKT"},
        {"Cornwall","CON"},
        {"Coventry","COV"},
        {"Craigavon","CGV"},
        {"Croydon","CRY"},
        {"Cumbria","CMA"},
        {"Darlington","DAL"},
        {"Denbighshire [Sir Ddinbych GB-DDB]","DEN"},
        {"Derby","DER"},
        {"Derbyshire","DBY"},
        {"Derry","DRY"},
        {"Devon","DEV"},
        {"Doncaster","DNC"},
        {"Dorset","DOR"},
        {"Down","DOW"},
        {"Dudley","DUD"},
        {"Dumfries and Galloway","DGY"},
        {"Dundee City","DND"},
        {"Dungannon","DGN"},
        {"Durham","DUR"},
        {"Ealing","EAL"},
        {"East Ayrshire","EAY"},
        {"East Dunbartonshire","EDU"},
        {"East Lothian","ELN"},
        {"East Renfrewshire","ERW"},
        {"East Riding of Yorkshire","ERY"},
        {"East Sussex","ESX"},
        {"Edinburgh, City of","EDH"},
        {"Eilean Siar","ELS"},
        {"Enfield","ENF"},
        {"Essex","ESS"},
        {"Falkirk","FAL"},
        {"Fermanagh","FER"},
        {"Fife","FIF"},
        {"Flintshire [Sir y Fflint GB-FFL]","FLN"},
        {"Gateshead","GAT"},
        {"Glasgow City","GLG"},
        {"Gloucestershire","GLS"},
        {"Greenwich","GRE"},
        {"Gwynedd","GWN"},
        {"Hackney","HCK"},
        {"Halton","HAL"},
        {"Hammersmith and Fulham","HMF"},
        {"Hampshire","HAM"},
        {"Haringey","HRY"},
        {"Harrow","HRW"},
        {"Hartlepool","HPL"},
        {"Havering","HAV"},
        {"Herefordshire, County of","HEF"},
        {"Hertfordshire","HRT"},
        {"Highland","HLD"},
        {"Hillingdon","HIL"},
        {"Hounslow","HNS"},
        {"Inverclyde","IVC"},
        {"Isle of Anglesey [Sir Ynys Môn GB-YNM]","AGY"},
        {"Isle of Wight","IOW"},
        {"Isles of Scilly","IOS"},
        {"Islington","ISL"},
        {"Kensington and Chelsea","KEC"},
        {"Kent","KEN"},
        {"Kingston upon Hull, City of","KHL"},
        {"Kingston upon Thames","KTT"},
        {"Kirklees","KIR"},
        {"Knowsley","KWL"},
        {"Lambeth","LBH"},
        {"Lancashire","LAN"},
        {"Larne","LRN"},
        {"Leeds","LDS"},
        {"Leicester","LCE"},
        {"Leicestershire","LEC"},
        {"Lewisham","LEW"},
        {"Limavady","LMV"},
        {"Lincolnshire","LIN"},
        {"Lisburn","LSB"},
        {"Liverpool","LIV"},
        {"London, City of","LND"},
        {"Luton","LUT"},
        {"Magherafelt","MFT"},
        {"Manchester","MAN"},
        {"Medway","MDW"},
        {"Merthyr Tydfil [Merthyr Tudful GB-MTU]","MTY"},
        {"Merton","MRT"},
        {"Middlesbrough","MDB"},
        {"Midlothian","MLN"},
        {"Milton Keynes","MIK"},
        {"Monmouthshire [Sir Fynwy GB-FYN]","MON"},
        {"Moray","MRY"},
        {"Moyle","MYL"},
        {"Neath Port Talbot [Castell-nedd Port Talbot GB-CTL]","NTL"},
        {"Newcastle upon Tyne","NET"},
        {"Newham","NWM"},
        {"Newport [Casnewydd GB-CNW]","NWP"},
        {"Newry and Mourne","NYM"},
        {"Newtownabbey","NTA"},
        {"Norfolk","NFK"},
        {"North Ayrshire","NAY"},
        {"North Down","NDN"},
        {"North East Lincolnshire","NEL"},
        {"North Lanarkshire","NLK"},
        {"North Lincolnshire","NLN"},
        {"North Somerset","NSM"},
        {"North Tyneside","NTY"},
        {"North Yorkshire","NYK"},
        {"Northamptonshire","NTH"},
        {"Northumberland","NBL"},
        {"Nottingham","NGM"},
        {"Nottinghamshire","NTT"},
        {"Oldham","OLD"},
        {"Omagh","OMH"},
        {"Orkney Islands","ORK"},
        {"Oxfordshire","OXF"},
        {"Pembrokeshire [Sir Benfro GB-BNF]","PEM"},
        {"Perth and Kinross","PKN"},
        {"Peterborough","PTE"},
        {"Plymouth","PLY"},
        {"Poole","POL"},
        {"Portsmouth","POR"},
        {"Powys","POW"},
        {"Reading","RDG"},
        {"Redbridge","RDB"},
        {"Redcar and Cleveland","RCC"},
        {"Renfrewshire","RFW"},
        {"Rhondda, Cynon, Taff [Rhondda, Cynon,Taf]","RCT"},
        {"Richmond upon Thames","RIC"},
        {"Rochdale","RCH"},
        {"Rotherham","ROT"},
        {"Rutland","RUT"},
        {"Salford","SLF"},
        {"Sandwell","SAW"},
        {"Scottish Borders, The","SCB"},
        {"Sefton","SFT"},
        {"Sheffield","SHF"},
        {"Shetland Islands","ZET"},
        {"Shropshire","SHR"},
        {"Slough","SLG"},
        {"Solihull","SOL"},
        {"Somerset","SOM"},
        {"South Ayrshire","SAY"},
        {"South Gloucestershire","SGC"},
        {"South Lanarkshire","SLK"},
        {"South Tyneside","STY"},
        {"Southampton","STH"},
        {"Southend-on-Sea","SOS"},
        {"Southwark","SWK"},
        {"St. Helens","SHN"},
        {"Staffordshire","STS"},
        {"Stirling","STG"},
        {"Stockport","SKP"},
        {"Stockton-on-Tees","STT"},
        {"Stoke-on-Trent","STE"},
        {"Strabane","STB"},
        {"Suffolk","SFK"},
        {"Sunderland","SND"},
        {"Surrey","SRY"},
        {"Sutton","STN"},
        {"Swansea [Abertawe GB-ATA]","SWA"},
        {"Swindon","SWD"},
        {"Tameside","TAM"},
        {"Telford and Wrekin","TFW"},
        {"Thurrock","THR"},
        {"Torbay","TOB"},
        {"Torfaen [Tor-faen]","TOF"},
        {"Tower Hamlets","TWH"},
        {"Trafford","TRF"},
        {"Vale of Glamorgan, The [Bro Morgannwg GB-BMG]","VGL"},
        {"Wakefield","WKF"},
        {"Walsall","WLL"},
        {"Waltham Forest","WFT"},
        {"Wandsworth","WND"},
        {"Warrington","WRT"},
        {"Warwickshire","WAR"},
        {"West Berkshire","WBK"},
        {"West Dunbartonshire","WDU"},
        {"West Lothian","WLN"},
        {"West Sussex","WSX"},
        {"Westminster","WSM"},
        {"Wigan","WGN"},
        {"Wiltshire","WIL"},
        {"Windsor and Maidenhead","WNM"},
        {"Wirral","WRL"},
        {"Wkingham","WOK"},
        {"Wolverhampton","WLV"},
        {"Worcestershire","WOR"},
        {"Wrexham [Wrecsam GB-WRC]","WRX"},
        {"York","YOR"}
    };

        public static SelectList StateSelectList
        {
            get { return new SelectList(UKStateDictionary, "Value", "Key"); }
        }
```

Comment: please standardize lines like this:`{"Rhondda, Cynon, Taff [Rhondda, Cynon,Taf]","RCT"}`

Comment: These three are part of the same abbreviation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhondda_Cynon_Taf

Comment: Consider using this ISO standard to maintain your list: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:GB